# Android SlidingDrawer from top?

Tags: android

Is there any way to make the drawer slide from top to bottom?

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer, which mekes it possible for you to slide from any side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default `SlidingDrawer` class doesn't allow this. You can use the `Panel` class from here to get something very similar though:
<strike>http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/</strike>

http://www.ohloh.net/p/android-misc-widgets

Comment: Did you get the Panels there working? I'm having a really hard time integrating that Panel, which seems to be very cool though. My issue is here, if somebody could look over it http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/issues/detail?id=9 The error says "Binary XML file line #15: The content attribute is required and must refer to a valid child."

Comment: I had to wrap the panel widget into a frame layout to get it working

Comment: The top-dropper had an unwanted behaviour: The content below was moved to the bottom. I fixed it this way: <FrameLayout><RelativeLayout><other stuff below/><panel/></RelativeLayout></FrameLayout>

Comment: Panel implementation doesn't work on phones such as HTC One and other 4.4 devices.

Answer (score 32):

I've found a simple way to do that. All you have to do is to set the rotation of 180º for the slidingDrawer, the content and the handle. It's easier to understand with an example, so look what I've done:

First, I'll show you my old SlidingDrawer, from bottom to top.

```
<SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:content="@+id/content">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Now look at the changes I made, setting the rotation of 180º

```
<SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:rotation="180">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:rotation="180" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:rotation="180" />
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Note that I also created a LinearLayout to set as handle, and didn't change it's rotation, but I changed the rotation of it's child. This was to prevent a small issue I had, but everything is working fine and it's simple.

Comment: Note `android:rotation` is API Level 11 (Android 3.0).

Comment: when I am running the application using the above layout the error is displaying  error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'rotation' in package 'android'

Comment: SlidingDrawer was deprecated in API level 17

Comment: this is best answer for me in stackoverflow :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

I was very unsatisfied with the solutions provided here:

- The `Panel` class from http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/ was really unintuitive to use and also had bugs and visual glitches (unusable for productive use) and no docs at all
- `SlidingTray` class from http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/ was nested in a lib needing too much dependency and for me, I did not get it to work at all
- using `android:rotation="180"` requires API Level 11, and my target is 10.

(no offense to the respective devs, trying to be objective here)

So my solution was to extract [SlidingTray](http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/com/sileria/android/view/SlidingTray.html) from this lib http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/ (by Ahmed Shakil) and
refactored it a bit since it had some quirks needed to be used within Ahmed's lib. `SlidingTray` is based on Androids own `SlidingDrawer`, so I guess it is stable. My modification consists of 1 class which I called `MultipleOrientationSlidingDrawer` and
you have to add declare-styleables in your attrs.xml. Other than that it has pretty much the same usage as [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)
with the additional "orientation" attribute..

**Check it out: [MultipleOrientationSlidingDrawer (source & example) @ gist](https://gist.github.com/patrickfav/6284130)**

Here is a usage example (also provided in the gist)

```xml
<your.app.MultipleOrientationSlidingDrawer
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/your.app"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        custom:handle="@+id/handle_c"
        custom:content="@+id/content_c"
        custom:orientation="top">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/handle_c"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="#333333">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Handle Text"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@id/content_c"
            android:background="#555555">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview_credits"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </your.app.MultipleOrientationSlidingDrawer>
```

Disclaimer: All the credits go to respective dev. I did not test this solution extensively, it works great
with TOP and BOTTOM set in XML. I did not try to use it programmatically.

Comment: It is good, but have you seen problem with animation ? Have you found a solution for blinking of view while it moving?

Comment: I did have blinking animiations with http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/ , but not with this apporach (so far)

Comment: Is it possible to make the ` FrameLayout`  `content_c` not to take up all available space because I see it  pushed everything down even do I set                         `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 6):

I had to do the same for one of my projects and I ended up writing my own widget for this. I called it **SlidingTray** is now part of my open source **Aniqroid** library.

http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/  (Look for downloads at the bottom or use google code project to see more download options: http://code.google.com/p/aniqroid/downloads/list)

The class documentation is here: http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/com/sileria/android/view/SlidingTray.html

Comment: I tried this one, but when I implement it using the xml example, I get a `nullpointer exception` at `com.sileria.android.Resource.getIdentifier`. Would love to use this.

Comment: Oops, looks like I forgot `Kit.init()`... Works great now!

Comment: Also if you copy/paste the XML example from the documentation, it's `com.sileria.android.view.SlidingTray` and not `com.sileria.android.SlidingTray`

Comment: its also not working and through **NullPointerException** @Peterdk !!

Comment: Your Kit.destroy() method does not work. onTerminate() wont get called on a real device only in emulator. There is no real way to get a callback when the app is "terminated" since the android paradigm does not work that way.

Comment: Hi Ahmed! Thanks for this library, I think it rocks. I have ONE problem : there seems to be a delay on my sliding drawer handle. It's not a time based delay but an x position based delay. I have to slide the handle for like 150px to the right before it starts reacting and moving accordingly... Any ideas?