# Is there a way to implement a top down sliding drawer

Tags: android, slider

In my app there a button , and on pressing it the requirement is that an expandable list view should slide out. but the case is that slidingdrawer only moves from bottom to top..

Comment: I think you are looking for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137350/how-to-make-an-android-slidingdrawer-slide-out-from-the-left and the answer by PHP_Jedi :-}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try umano's https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel. Just copy it and see if it fits

Answer (score 2):

This was asked in a similar question: [Android SlidingDrawer from top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695856/android-slidingdrawer-from-top)

To summarize, there are basically two solutions:

1. On Android 3.0+ (API 11), you can set android:rotation on the SlidingDrawer to 180 degree.  And since that will also rotate the children, rotate them an additional 180 degree, to return them to their original orientation.  **However**, since SlidingDrawer was also deprecated in Android 4.2 (API 17), this solution is not recommended as anything more than an interim solution.
2. The better solution is to write you own implementation or use a similar component from a 3rd party widget library.  A few library recommendations can be found in the answers for this question: [SlidingDrawer deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478993/slidingdrawer-deprecated)