# How to make OnDrawerOpenListener() work in android

Tags: android, label, deprecated, ontouchlistener, slidingdrawer

Can someone explain how to get this to work please. Says its deprecated, just wondering if I can force it or if there is another way to change my title label when the SlidingDrawer is opened then change it back when it is closed. I still have a lot to learn so if possible please reply with something that is cut and paste friendly ;) Thanks.

Jesse

```
        OnDrawerCloseListener onClick_DrawerClosed = new OnDrawerCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed() {
                titletext.setText("Flow Charts");    
            }
        };


        OnDrawerOpenListener onClick_DrawerOpened = new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened() {
                titletext.setText("Options Menu");
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

SlidingDrawer in general is deprecated as of API 17 (the latest). This doesn't mean you can't use SlidingDrawer and it's methods, but that it's "frowned upon" and Eclipse will give you warnings. You can make those go away by right clicking on the warnings and selecting "Suppress..."

Look here for a more thorough discussion:

[SlidingDrawer deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478993/slidingdrawer-deprecated)

Comment: Thanks ,but the code I posted above doesn't do anything. Do you know of a way to achieve the desired outcome?