# sliding drawer - deprecated

Tags: java, android, slidingdrawer

Q - Why was sliding drawer deprecated in API level 17 ?

I have been reading at many sources but could not find an appropriate answer. Same question was asked here : [SlidingDrawer deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478993/slidingdrawer-deprecated) but got no proper answers.

Thanks

Comment: The Android documentation too does not offer any reason. See : [Sliding Drawer - Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

Comment: Why is always a question for the guys/girls who did it :). Probably no good reason for this but...

Comment: As Marko indicates, usually the only people who can answer "why" on questions like this are Googlers, and the odds of your getting a Googly answer here are not very good. So, you are welcome to participate in an Android Developer Office Hours that Google runs via Google+ and ask them. Or, you are welcome to attend Google I|O 2014 and ask them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SlidingDrawer deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478993/slidingdrawer-deprecated)

Answer (score 2):

Why? To me it's pretty clear why it's deprecated - it just doesn't go with the Holo look and feel.