# can android animation change view's size

Tags: android, animation

is it possible that change the image size by animation? what I want to achieve is I have an `imageView`,and I want to use an animation to resize it.make it bigger ,like I set it **200dip** in xml file,after the animation it become **500dip**.is that possible?what methods should I use exactly?any help and guideness will be highly appeciate.thank you:D.

or can realize this effect.

EDIT:

I think I need to make it more clear,I have a screen **800dip**.and two view ,first is **200dip**,another is **600dip**.so the second size is calculate by `screen size - first size`,and I wonder if I change the first imageView size to **600dip** by animation,and of course the second imageView become **200** automatic,could that happen?

Comment: And what have you tried, exactly?

Comment: If you are using ScaleAnimation already, you can set property setFillAfter(true);

Comment: @m0skit0 I have update please have a look

Comment: @ShreyaS I have update please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Your animation changes view hierarchi params so you should apply new layout params (lp) to ImageView.

Create custom animation which will apply new lp to ImageView setting different width/height on every frame. So your image view will increase it's size and move other views. There are a lot examples how to implement this. [Take a look at this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165682/how-to-implement-expandable-panels-in-android).

```
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = (int) (mStartHeight + mDeltaHeight * interpolatedTime);
        mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
```

Comment: wow ,this looks like what i want,is that a scaleanimation?should I binding the height with the animation's time? now I use a timer,every 50ms make the height change ,but the effect looks stupid.

Comment: @SweetLady Hi can you provide any sample for this?