# SlidingOut the subList from top in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Hey guys i am trying to slide  a childview of an expandableListView from top.I have a achieved this by Translate animation on the convertView returned from getChildView of the adapter.But the childView is sliding over the parentView of the childView( groupView of the list ).here is the [anim xml](http://pastebin.com/Rq2hGgss) file i am using to translate  .Please tell me how to slide child view behind the parentView ?

I have already seen the solutions to use a ListView instead of ExpandableListView for such animations but i need to use ExpandableListView only.

Please suggest me some solutions.

Thanx in advance

Comment: have a look at this question. It might have a answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495178/how-open-sub-window-with-three-buttons-on-clicked-list-item-like-shown-in-screen/15495541#15495541

Comment: @Neil : That answer doesn't say anything translating a view or ExpandableListView.