# ExpandablePanel Layout

Tags: android, expandable

My expandable panel is not working as it should.
I'll show the pictures:

In normal state it should be like this

[image]

After expand, it should be like this

[image]

And after collapse it should return to normal state.

Now it work like here:

Normal state:

[image]

After expand it works like collapse state:

[image].

And i have not to use expandable list view, i need layout works like expandable view.

So, what's wrong with code?

```
public class ExpandablePanel extends LinearLayout {

private int mHandleId;
private int mContentId;
private int mViewGroupId;

private boolean isViewGroup;

private View mHandle;
private View mContent;
private ViewGroup viewGroup;

private boolean mExpanded = false;
private int mCollapsedHeight = 0;
private int mContentHeight = 0;
private int mAnimationDuration = 0;

private OnExpandListener mListener;

public ExpandablePanel(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ExpandablePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        init(context, attrs);
    }
}

private void init (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    if (isInEditMode()) return;

    mListener = new DefaultOnExpandListener();

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandablePanel, 0, 0);

    // How high the content should be in "collapsed" state
    mCollapsedHeight = (int) a.getDimension(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_collapsedHeight, 0.0f);

    // How long the animation should take
    mAnimationDuration = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_animationDuration, 500);

    int handleId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_handle, 0);
    if (handleId == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The handle attribute is required and must refer "
                        + "to a valid child.");
    }

    int contentId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_content, 0);
    if (contentId == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The content attribute is required and must refer to a valid child.");
    }

    int isViewGroupId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_isviewgroup, 0);
    int viewGroupId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_viewgroup, 0);
    isViewGroup = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_isviewgroup, false);
    if (isViewGroup) {
        mViewGroupId = viewGroupId;
    }
    else {
        mViewGroupId = 0;
    }

    mHandleId = handleId;
    mContentId = contentId;

    a.recycle();
}

public void setOnExpandListener(OnExpandListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public void setCollapsedHeight(int collapsedHeight) {
    mCollapsedHeight = collapsedHeight;
}

public void setAnimationDuration(int animationDuration) {
    mAnimationDuration = animationDuration;
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    mHandle = findViewById(mHandleId);
    if (mHandle == null) {

        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The handle attribute is must refer to an"
                            + " existing child.");
        }
    }
    if(mViewGroupId != 0) {
        viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(mViewGroupId);
    }


    mContent = findViewById(mContentId);
    if (mContent == null) {

        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The content attribute must refer to an"
                            + " existing child.");
        }
    }

    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = mCollapsedHeight;
        mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);

        mHandle.setOnClickListener(new PanelToggler());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // First, measure how high content wants to be
    if (isInEditMode()) return;

    mContent.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    mContentHeight = mContent.getMeasuredHeight();

    if (mContentHeight < mCollapsedHeight) {
        viewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else {
        viewGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // Then let the usual thing happen
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

private class PanelToggler implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Animation a;
        if (mExpanded) {
            a = new ExpandAnimation(mContentHeight, mCollapsedHeight);
            mListener.onCollapse(mHandle, mContent);
        } else {
            a = new ExpandAnimation(mCollapsedHeight, mContentHeight);
            mListener.onExpand(mHandle, mContent);
        }
        a.setDuration(mAnimationDuration);
        if(mContent.getLayoutParams().height == 0) //Need to do this or else the animation will not play if the height is 0
        {
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams();
            lp.height = 1;
            mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
            mContent.requestLayout();
        }
        mContent.startAnimation(a);
        mExpanded = !mExpanded;
    }
}

private class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
    private final int mStartHeight;
    private final int mDeltaHeight;

    public ExpandAnimation(int startHeight, int endHeight) {
        mStartHeight = startHeight;
        mDeltaHeight = endHeight - startHeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = (int) (mStartHeight + mDeltaHeight * interpolatedTime);
        mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}

public interface OnExpandListener {
    public void onExpand(View handle, View content);
    public void onCollapse(View handle, View content);
}

private class DefaultOnExpandListener implements OnExpandListener {
    public void onCollapse(View handle, View content) {}
    public void onExpand(View handle, View content) {}
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:example="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<ExpandablePanel
    android:id="@+id/expandablePanel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    example:collapsedHeight="50dip"
    example:content="@+id/group_layout"
    example:handle="@+id/group_layout"
    example:isviewgroup="true"
    example:viewgroup="@+id/childLayout" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/group_layout"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/childLayout"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
<ExpandablePanel>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its your xml problem

Answer (score 1):

First Of all please set **`Open-Close`** Tag This way

### Whats Your Problem

Your Root Layout **LinearLayout** Close Tag  .
Please [how-to-implement-expandable-panels-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165682/how-to-implement-expandable-panels-in-android) Check this .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:example="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ExpandablePanel
        android:id="@+id/expandablePanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        example:collapsedHeight="50dip"
        example:content="@+id/group_layout"
        example:handle="@+id/group_layout"
        example:isviewgroup="true"
        example:viewgroup="@+id/childLayout" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/group_layout"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/childLayout"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
    <ExpandablePanel>

</LinearLayout>
```