# Pull down list menu in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to create a List view. However this list view is somewhat of a pull down menu. That is, I have to create a button on top of screen, where on clicking it, a list view will be displayed (pulled down) from top.

Can some one give me an idea about this? I mean, what is this component in Android and how do I go about it creating it?

I know the normal way of creating a list view but not this.

Comment: I think you are referring to a `Spinner`

Comment: [Spinner Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)

Comment: He is not referring to a spinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey thanks all for your replies i finally got want i wanted to implement.The following link helped me achieve it:
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/08/android-sliding-drawer-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would use a Single Choice Dialog.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it Pull-down-from-top. You'll need to use `Panel` Custom view from [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/) project.
If a pull-from-below will suffice, use a [Sliding Drawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html). (From Android 3.0, Sliding Drawer can be configured to be pulled down aswell. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695856/android-slidingdrawer-from-top))

Have the Listview inside the Drawer/Panel.

Comment: Thnx @stOle ,I will try implement this and reply.Thankyou once again

Comment: FYI, The SlidingDrawer class [was deprecated in API level 17](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

Comment: Yes it is, so anyone found any other solution for the same?