# Android Pull down fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe

I am trying to get an effect that is similar to navigation drawer only the swipe would come from the top of the screen, much like the notifaction center in android:

this is what i need to do:
[image]

what i want is for a specific fragment to always be there and can be brougt to the view by pulling down, anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: I think if you have VIEW with you, then you can do this.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean, what is this effect called? how can i implement it? once i can do this i will place my fragment inside of it.

Comment: You can do this using SlidindDrawer, for reference read this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695856/android-slidingdrawer-from-top

Comment: the question you reffered to, states that sliding drawer will not work and also this is depracated and is now implemented using navigation drawer, however it does not have top -to - bottom implemantation, do you know of any other methods? i came across this:
https://github.com/grantland/android-verticalpager
but i cant really understand how toy use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually mennaged to get this effect using this awsome and grate library!:
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel
Free to user and amasingly effective.