# Android sliding drawer from top to bottom

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I want to create sliding drawer in android which should be placed on top of the activity and should be open from top to bottom like android notification panel. How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695856/android-slidingdrawer-from-top

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227689/1641556

Answer (score 1):

The default `SlidingDrawer` class doesn't allow this. You can use the Panel class from here to get something very similar though OR set the rotation of 180º for the `SlidingDrawer`, the content and the handle. **Note : android:rotation is support on API > Level 11**

http://www.ohloh.net/p/android-misc-widgets
https://github.com/IanDarwin/Android-Cookbook-Examples/tree/master/SlidingDrawer-Topdown

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227689/1641556)

Comment: I am not able to run cookbook example its giving me error as                  03-02 16:44:06.023: E/AndroidRuntime(21584): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slidingdrawer/com.example.slidingdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your Panel must have a View whose id attribute is 'R.id.panelHandle'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have sliding drawer from top to bottom then just copy pase this code in your project, it is 100% working code.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#d3d3d3"
    >
    <SlidingDrawer
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rotation="180" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:gravity="right"
       android:background="@+drawable/drawer_bk"
           >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@+drawable/drawer1" />



    </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:rotation="180" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView04"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="visit"
            android:src="@drawable/visit_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageView04"
            android:onClick="contact_us"
            android:src="@drawable/contact_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView04"
            android:onClick="logout"
            android:src="@drawable/singout_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

  </SlidingDrawer>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 {

/** Duration of wait **/
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 4000;
Button slideButton,b1, b2,b3,b4;
SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //slideButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slideButton);
    slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer);
     slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened()
        {
           // slideButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_arrow_icon);
            slidingDrawer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hd_img_1);
        }
    });

    slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed() 
        {

          //  slideButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.upwar_arrow_icon);
            slidingDrawer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    });

   }
}
```